# How can I automate logging into Linux server and running git fetch/pull on a website?

Tags: linux, git, github

Here's what I want to do:

- I have a hosted website on a Linux server.
- This site is pointed to a GitHub repository.
- I want to be able to push changes to the repository, then be able to log into my website and click a button to have the site pull the new code in order to update itself.

Here's how I do it manually:

- I created a file on the Linux server called `update_site`
- I log into my Linux server via ssh and type `.\update_site` which goes to the site's directory and executes a fetch and pull
- the first time it asked me to enter my login and password which I did
- but since I had set `git config --global credential.helper store`, it never asks me again

Here's how I want to automate it:

- I created a PHP file which executes the file `update_site`
- However, since the PHP website is apparently executing code as another user, it doesn't have my credentials for GitHub

Here's my question:

- How can I automate the process so that when the website executes the `update_site` file, my GitHub login and password are sent as well. And needless to say, how can I do this as securely as possible, i.e. without saving my GitHub password somewhere as plain text?

Comment: Are you OK to have maximum 10 (or 5) minutes between push the chages and apply the code to the server?

Comment: @RomeoNinov That would be tolerable, yes. Although when I do this manually, the changes are immediate, or what is the gist of your question?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this automation is to use `cron`. Edit your `cron` record (with `crontab -e` command) and add line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/update_site
```

In above line 5 mean every 5 minutes